# How to set zypper to detailed mode by default?

Tags: opensuse, zypper

It is equal to type "d" here:

```
1 new package to install.
Overall download size: 1.0 MiB. Already cached: 0 B. After the operation, additional 6.7 MiB will be used.
Continue? [y/n/v/...? shows all options] (y):
```

In such case zypper shows all in columns and becomes more informative:

[image: glances]

So I just need to get the same "d" behaviour by default (for each zypper usage).

Comment: Don't post pictures/screenshots of text. In this case I recommend you copy and paste the content of the image in your question.

Comment: It is pasted as image to show layout only, text does not matter in such case.

Answer (score 1):

From `man zypper`:

> --details
>
> > Show the detailed installation summary.

So you if you are installing some package(s) (e.g. `fish`) you should use:

```bash
sudo zypper install --details fish
```

The same applies for other `zypper` options such as `remove`,`update`,`dist-upgrade`, etc.

You can create an **alias** in `~/.bashrc`,`~/.zshrc` (according to your shell) to avoid typing the whole command each time:

```bash
alias zypinsd='sudo zypper install --details'
```

So now, instead of typing the whole command you can use:

```bash
zypinsd fish
```

Comment: So it means we cannot do it in some config as I understood it. Creation alias will be problematic. It means you need to create it for each command for example "zypper update". So as result you will have commands zoo. So my question was exactly how to avoid this --details in command line, like for example can be omitted --no-recomends (enabled by default in config).

Comment: @Maxim It seems is not possible. I tried searching in the manual as well as in wikis/forums but nothing useful (only for `--no-recomends` and other options such as kernel versions,etc.). I guess what you can do is  create a function called `zypper` and inside this one specify `--details` for options such as `install`, `update`, `remove`...